# How to create boolean queries on excel including two or more items in a list?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, booleanquery

I'm trying to create a boolean query in excel that will include every variation of any two items in a list.

To demonstrate, let's say my dataset is:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I'd like to create a formula which outputs `("A" AND "B") OR ("A" AND "C") OR ("A" AND "D") OR ("B" AND "C") OR ("B" AND "D") OR...` etc. Its not a big deal if it includes, for example `("A" AND "B")... ("B" AND "A")`.

My dataset is much bigger than four so it's extremely time consuming to do this manually.

Comment: What is your intended result or usage for such as result? There are a number of ways to accomplish this, including setting up a helper column that "translates" the ABCD values into numbers and "adds" them in a way to calculate the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your request literally:

`=LET(ζ,A1:A4,ξ,ROWS(ζ),TEXTJOIN(" OR ",,IF(SEQUENCE(ξ)<SEQUENCE(,ξ),"("&ζ&" AND "&TRANSPOSE(ζ)&")","")))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jos - if I wanted to modify it to include x number of those terms, like ("A" AND "B" AND "C") where x = 3, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
=LET(data,A1:A4,
   cnt,COUNTA(data),
   m,MAKEARRAY(cnt,cnt,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r<c,"("""&INDEX(data,r)&""" and """&INDEX(data,c)&""")",""))),
   TEXTJOIN(" OR ",TRUE,m))
```

It will return `("A" and "B") OR ("A" and "C") OR ("A" and "D") OR ("B" and "C") OR ("B" and "D") OR ("C" and "D")` for A to D in A1:A4.